# Error on checkout "Carrier with such method not found:"

Tags: magento2

I am creating custom shipping extension, while on checkout my custom rate shown as:

[image]

But i am getting error when check this carrier to place order.
Error is:

[image]

Comment: i have facing same error you have any idea reply

Comment: remove underscore from your custom module code like in my case it was $_code = 'Instore_Pickup'; and i changed it to $_code = 'InstorePickup';

Comment: is this solution work for you ?

Comment: No but you share your opinion so thank for you

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when the table quote_shipping_rate does not have the correct shipping method data. In order to figure out what is going on, you can use this checklist:

1. Truncate the table quote_shipping_rate.
2. Verify the code of your Shipping module. When the rates are created, the module should set the data as follows:

   $rate = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

   $rate->setCarrier($this->_code); //carrier code (ex. fedex)

   $rate->setMethod($method); //method code (ex. 2_DAY_DELIVERY)

   $rate->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title')); //carrier title (ex. Fedex)

   $rate->setMethodTitle($methodTitle); //method title (ex. 2-Day delivery)

   $rate->setCost($price); //rate cost (ex. 10.99)

   $rate->setPrice($price); //rate price (ex. 10.99)

All fields are important and even though they are not all required, if you skip any of them, it will risk the same error to happen again.

3. Place a new order or at least follow the process until a point where the error is displayed.
4. Now that you have already placed the order or received the error message again, verify the data on quote_shipping_rate. It should look like this:

[image: Table quote_shipping_rate]
Pay attention to the fields **carrier**, **carrier_title**, **code**, and **method**. One of them will have data different from your module. Also note that "**code**" is a concatenation of **"carrier"_"method"**, so if your method code or carrier code has too many characters, it is possible that the field code has an invalid data. None of these fields can be empty and all of them should match the data in your shipping module.